# map reduce on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm starting with map reduce on `mongodb` and I'm using this reduce function

```
function(key, values) { 
  print("reduce key=" + key + " values=" + values);
  return Array.sum(values); 
}
```

I use the print to see what is happenning inside the function and I see this on the log

```
[conn32] reduce key=3 values=122400,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2021-03-19T19:18:32.123+0000 I - [conn32] reduce key=3 values=122500,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2021-03-19T19:18:32.125+0000 I - [conn32] reduce key=3 values=122600,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I see the key 3 several times, it's not supposed that  in reduce function thee is only a key-value pair per key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/index.html#requirements-for-the-reduce-function):

> The values argument is an array whose elements are the value objects that are “mapped” to the key.

> MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key.